# TYPO3 tx_form - How to generate a pdf with the input values provided an attach it to email

Tags: typo3, pdf-generation, typo3-8.x

I'm using TYPO3 tx_form for an application. How can I generate a pdf with the input values provided and attach it to an email and then send it to different recepients?

Comment: Maybe you could use ext:pdfviewhelpers to help you with that. Simply load the form values from DB and let the extension to its job. (It supports sending a PDF file via email attachment)